# Custom class objects might be null. How can I tell my initializer this?

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a class I made that I fill with some JSON data.  A couple properties in the class MIGHT be null in some cases.  I thought I prepared for this but when I try to access the class and one of the properties are null I get an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.  This error only pops if the value of one of the properties is null.  Here's my class:

```
class Inventory {
    private var _id, _quantityOnHand: Int!;
    private var _item, _description: String!;
    private var _supplierId: Int?;
    private var _supplierName: String?;

    var id: Int {
        get {
            return _id;
        }
    }

    var item: String {
        get {
            return _item;
        }
    }

    //    ... removed for brevity

    var supplierId: Int {
        get {
            return _supplierId!;
        }
    }

    var supplierName: String {
        get {
            return _supplierName!;  //this is where error is when value is null
        }
    }

    init(id: Int, item: String, description: String, quantityOnHand: Int, supplierId: Int?, supplierName: String?) {
        _id = id;
        _item = item;
        _description = description;
        _quantityOnHand = quantityOnHand;
        _supplierId = supplierId;
        _supplierName = supplierName;

    }
}
```

The fields `supplierId` and `supplierName` MIGHT possibly be null (not always though.  When I run my application and it tries to get the value from one of the null properties I get the error.

I tried removing the ! forced unwrapped from my getter but it won't compile and complains about it.

I have a `UITableView` with a segue the sends the information to the next view controller.  In it I'm putting all the values of the tapped row of the `UITableView` into variables.  Here's the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueToItemDetail" {
            if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? InventoryItemViewController {
                if let itemIndex = inventoryListTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                    destination.idInt = warehouseItems[itemIndex].id;
                    destination.itemString = warehouseItems[itemIndex].item;
                    destination.descriptionString
                        = warehouseItems[itemIndex].description;
                    destination.supplierNameString = warehouseItems[itemIndex].supplierName ?? "";
                    destination.quantityOnHandInt = warehouseItems[itemIndex].quantityOnHand;

                }
            }
        }
```

I tried using a Nil Coalescing Operator on the properties that might be null but it still throws the error when trying to pass any values that are null.

Why can't I satiate these optionals?

Comment: Either change the `supplierName` getter to return a `String?` so you don't have to force unwrap it or leave it as `String` and change it to `return _supplierName ?? ""`.

Comment: It also seems like what I think you are trying to do with the public getter for private property would be much simpler if you declared them as `private(set) public var supplierName: String?` which would allow you to set them inside the class but only get from outside

Comment: For basic types `Int` and `String` consider to use non-optional `0` and `""` as `nil` representation. It avoids the overhead to handle the optionals.

Comment: @dan adding `return _supplierName ?? ""` worked perfectly.  I wasn't able to set the getter to return a String? without the compiler complaining about force unwrapping it.

Comment: @vadian That's why I used the Nil Coalescent for the string.  I'll definitely add 0 for the int.  Thanks!  I still have so much to learn with optionals and swift.

Comment: For a read-only variable you don't need a private backing variable. Just declare the variable as constant (`let`). This constant can be set once in the `init` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your design can live with empty string for "no String value" and 0 for "no Int value" this is a much easier syntax (simplified with 3 properties). Due to the declaration as constant all properties are treated as read-only without a private backing variable.

```
class Inventory {

  let id, supplierId: Int
  let supplierName: String

  init(id: Int, supplierId: Int?, supplierName: String?) {
    self.id = id
    self.supplierId = supplierId ?? 0
    self.supplierName = supplierName ?? ""
  }
}
```

Rather than `if supplierName == nil` you can check `if supplierName.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var supplierId: Int? {
     return _supplierId;
}

var supplierName: String? {
    return _supplierName;  //return optional value
}
```

Don't forcefully unwrap your iVars while getting its value, rather check it when using it's value.

**For your information :**

when you have only `get` block directly return value instead of writing `get block`.

https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide